# When making a c++ DLL, must I repeat extern"C" and __declspec(dllexport/import) on the definition of the functions?

Tags: c++, dll

given the following declaration layout:

.h

```
extern "C"{

    __declspec(dllexport) int foo();
}
```

when defining that function in the .cpp, should we repeat the extern "C" and __declspec(dllexport) like this?:

.cpp

```
extern "C"{
    __declspec(dllexport) int foo(){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

why or why not?

further, what difference does it make if it is not necessary?

Comment: No, you do not need to duplicate the `extern "C"` and `__declspec(dllexport)` on the function definitions if they are already on the declarations.

Comment: @RemyLebeau as long as the header is actually included in the .cpp file, right? (I know it should be a given, but still, you never know)

Comment: @Jeffrey true enough